# MySQL slow join on very basic query, indexes, foreign keys, and everything seem in alignment

Tags: mysql, inner-join, query-performance

I have two schemas, both are identical, one with about 5x less data in it, and the queries are slower by a factor of 120x with the same indexes, foreign keys, database server, and anything else I could think of to check.

Here are the two queries:

```
-- Bigger Database, takes .5 seconds, has ~900k and 80 records

select *
  from schemaA.bb_quote
  inner join schemaA.scb_user
    ON scb_user.usr_uid = bb_quote.q_usr_uid
  order by q_quoteid desc
  limit 20;

-- smaller database, takes 2 minutes, has ~211k and 4 records

select *
  from schemaB.bb_quote
  inner join schemaB.scb_user
    ON scb_user.usr_uid = bb_quote.q_usr_uid
  order by q_quoteid desc
  limit 20;
```

I ran the following to explain commands and the explains are different.

```
explain select *
          from schemaA.bb_quote
          inner join schemaA.scb_user
            ON scb_user.usr_uid = bb_quote.q_usr_uid
          order by q_quoteid desc
          limit 20;
```

[image: Quick Query]

```
explain select *
          from schemaB.bb_quote
          inner join schemaB.scb_user
            ON scb_user.usr_uid = bb_quote.q_usr_uid
          order by q_quoteid desc
          limit 20;
```

[image]

The second one ends up with a very different explain. I am not sure what next debugging steps to take.

I have read many times that this is the result of their not being enough ram, and it needing to create a file to do it's work. This is running in AWS RDS, and the monitoring does have a ~20gig drop utilized hard drive space, then it recovers all that memory, while the other query does not do that.

What is the best way to tell what is different between these two schemas?

## Debugging Done

- Dropping and rebuilding the schema with mysqldump the problem still occurs.
- Dropping and recreating the foreign key involved
- Testing ~12 other schemas all the same

## Additional Information from Comments

- Version = MySQL 5.5.46
- q_quoteid is in the bb_quote table
- EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT doesn't work, I don't think it is supported by this version of MySQL

Comment: HELP!  What table is `q_quoteid` in??

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Can you provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for each case?

Comment: Version = MySQL 5.5.46

Comment: q_quoteid is in the bb_quote table

Comment: EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT doesn't work, I don't think it is supported by this version of MySQL

Comment: I have a similar setup in Google cloud and I observed that the type of hard disk being used matters a lot. Are both your databases running on SSD? I observed a significant performance drop when I used HDD instead of SSD.

Comment: We are not currently running SSDs, however, that is a good change to make regardless. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are 3 major versions behind.  There have been a number of Optimizer improvements since 5.5.  Upgrade!  (And, yeah, JSON was added in 5.6.)

Comment: Version SSD + 5.6 + Moving to it's own instance all helped with the speed alot, still using a temp table, but the symptoms are different now. I will keep you guys apprised as we move forward, but I have a feeling moving forward is our best path.